# Cannot Change URL to SEO Friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to change my URL, I have search much more from Google, Stackoverflow etc..., I see many examples but nothing is working in my code so, please help me. here is my URL :

`mydomain.com/page.php?cat=abc&scat=xyz&id=1`

and I want to make URL like this :

`mydomain.com/page/abc/xyz/1`

and after rewriting this URL I can get query string from URL. And I want redirect for only this `page.php`, other files must not be affected. I have tried this code but it is not working properly:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/page/.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/page/.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What are examples of other URLs that are being wrongly handled, and what are the resulting (wrong) URLs for all of these? Please [edit] your question to add these.

Comment: Nothing resulting wrong, but my URL become like this [mydomain.com/page.php?cat=abc&scat=xyz&id=1] and I want URL like this [mydomain.com/page/abc/xyz/1] that's All.